# Symfony Permission Error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

Trying to install the SymfonyCMF and I keep getting errors on the permissions on app/cache and app/logs.  I have the permissions of these folders set to 0777, but I am still getting this error.  How can I get Symfony to see that the permissions are set correctly?

Comment: remove browser cache and once again try to install symfony

Comment: where do you get the errors regarding permissions? or, how did you figure it was a permissions issue?

Comment: did you follow https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox#setup-filesystem-permissions ? when you use the sandbox with sqlite, you need to make sure that both the sqlite file and the folder it is in are writeable by the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

To set the correct permissions for Symfony, run these two commands as root inside your project directory. Here, "user" is your Linux user's name. Also. it is assumed that apache is running with the process name apache. In Ubuntu, you will have to use www-data instead of apache.

```
 setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwx -m u:user:rwx app/cache app/logs
 setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwx -m u:user:rwx app/cache app/logs
```